# Deserialize a Json Object with square bracket

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to deserialize json object but getting error. Can somebody help me. here is the example

```
[
 {
  "heading": "some data",
  "company name":"some data",
  "href":"link"
 },
 {
  "heading": "some data",
  "company name":"some data",
  "href":"link"
 },
 {
  "heading": "some data",
  "company name":"some data",
  "href":"link"
 }
]
```

here is how i am trying to deserializeobject. mentioned json data is coming from api and is inside model under Class1 (public Class Class1)

```
 public class Class1:ParentObject
 {
   public string something{get; set;}
   public string something{get; set;}
   public string something{get; set;}
 }
```

inside controller

```
 ParentObject a=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(responseData);
```

error i am getting is Cannot deserialize the current Json array because the type requires a JSOn object......
will be a great help

Comment: Since the error specifies a JSON *object*, try changing it to an object. Simply wrap it in `{...}` and give it a key. e.g. `{"values": [ {...}, {...}, {...} ] }`. An array by itself should be well-formed JSON, but your parser could be requiring an object.

Comment: Oh, wait, no, it's probably just failing on your trailing comma. You can always try pasting your JSON into https://jsonlint.com/ if you ever want to verify if something is valid JSON.

Comment: The Response Json is coming from third party api so i do not have control over it.

Comment: Well, you'll have to deal with it, because they're not sending you valid JSON. That's assuming your code up top is really what they're sending. You could edit the string before sending it to the parser, if the error is always consistent. Or you can tell the 3rd party API to fix their JSON.

Comment: i checked if this is valid in jsonlint.com and is valid

Comment: When you are given JSON and you need to parse it, the first thing you should do is head over to http://json2csharp.com, plug in the JSON, and get the C# classes back.

Comment: "i checked if this is valid in jsonlint.com and is valid" -- well, you edited your question, so *now* it is valid, yes. That's why I said "assuming your code up top is really what they're sending."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data being sent is an array. The enclosed model looks like this when parsed using one of the many online utilities.

```
public class Model : ParentObject {
    public string heading { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("company name")] //<-- needed because of the space in the property name
    public string companyname { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
}
```

You would need to deserialize the JSON as an array in order to use it.

```
Model[] a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model[]>(responseData);
```

Comment: It fixed the json deserialize error but had another one. Since i was using ParentObject the view will look for ParentObject and throw error. The model item passed into the dictionary is of type [] but requires ParentObject.

Comment: Then change the model to suit your class and update the view to expect a collection if that is what you need otherwise extract one from the array and return that instead

Comment: Is there any way to do something like ParentObject Model[] a= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model[]>(responseDate);

Comment: This view is rendering other data as well which is working fine (and with ParentObject) but this part was responding as array so i had this problem.